# image problem after publishing my website

Tags: css, image

when i code my website in atom,the images i added inside the code is perfectly working. On publishing  it on github it successfully uploaded,but the images that were perfectly working is now not showing in the website.please help to resolve this.

Comment: Could you provide link to github repo or something that we could have reference of what u are talking about

Comment: Please provide the code that you used or the link to the page

Comment: this is the link of website    https://taskmaster682.github.io/sayed-anwar/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change out all instances of `C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\web development\THIS IS ME` with `https://taskmaster682.github.io/sayed-anwar` in your code because the image references are no longer relative to the path on your computer.

So:
`C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\web development\THIS IS ME\images\IMG_20200226_101136.png`

Would become: `https://taskmaster682.github.io/sayed-anwar/images/IMG_20200226_101136.png`

Comment: thanks a lot bro.it works. https://taskmaster682.github.io/sayed-anwar/.this the link